# Excel Function Return Max Two Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to get some help with a function that I am sure is an option but I sadly have no clue on how to implement.

Basically, I'd like a formula to go from C21:C50 and look for the top two values. Based upon which two are the top, it would reference the name in B column and populate that value in the another cell (the cell the formula resides in)

[image: Example Image]

If you look at the image, in the primary field, we'd have Steve. Secondary would be Alan.

Is this something anyone can help with? I simply am lost :(

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$7,MATCH(LARGE($C$3:$C$7,ROW(A1)),$C$3:$C$7,0))
```

with Bob in cell B3 and the "primary" formula in cell C9. Copy down to cell C10.

[image]

Comment: That sort of works. However, it is having difficulty with if a column has multiples of the same value. Is there a way to offset that?

Comment: That scenario was not in your data sample. Build a data sample that shows the issue and explain the logic that leads to the desired result. Edit your question to do that. Do not post that in a comment. Post a comment when you've made your edit, so people get alerted.

Answer (score 1):

If dealing with integers, you can simply add `+1/ROW([range])` to avoid doubles:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$7,MATCH(LARGE($C$3:$C$7+1/ROW($C$3:$C$7),ROW(A1)),$C$3:$C$7+1/ROW($C$3:$C$7),0))
```

> This is an array-formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>!

---

However, this may fail for numbers like 5.01 or 4.99. For that case just use it in combination with `RANK.EQ`:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$7,MATCH(LARGE(RANK.EQ($C$3:$C$7,$C$3:$C$7,1)+1/ROW($C$3:$C$7),ROW(A1)),RANK.EQ($C$3:$C$7,$C$3:$C$7,1)+1/ROW($C$3:$C$7),0))
```

> This is an array-formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>!

---

The steps as picture:

[image: example]

The first table shows the direct adding of `1/ROW` which is used for `LARGE` and `MATCH` to get the row if doubles exist (so `INDEX` can pick the correct one)

The second table shows how the values get replaced by their rank with `RANK.EQ` and then are treated the same like the first table.

The third (grey) table shows, what would happen if the first formula is applied to the second table (to demonstrate how the ranks get messed up).

---

For Excel 2007 just replace the `RANK.EQ($C$3:$C$7,$C$3:$C$7,1)` with `RANK($C$3:$C$7,$C$3:$C$7,1)`.

---

If you still have any questions, just ask :)